# Is there any python API to collect kubernetes VPA data

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have enabled the VPA on cluster as read only mode and tried to collect the VPA recommendation data. But I could not find a good documentation or any API details specific to the Vertical Pod Autoscaling. I have found it for the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler but not for the VPA.

Comment: From what I see in the python client library, there is neither documentation or API created for VPA at this moment. There is only documentation and API created for the [HPA](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AutoscalingV1Api.md).

Comment: Did you figure out a way? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes @SaeidGhafouri I did little different way. I used GVK API to query using custom object API. I listed all the namespaces using `corev1api` and then did `list_namespaced_custom_object(group="autoscaling.k8s.io", version="v1", namespace=<namespace-name>, plural="verticalpodautoscalers")`

Comment: thank you, what is GVK api?

Comment: Group Version Kind [little description](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/gvks.html). So API will be something like this [list_namespaced_custom_object](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#list_namespaced_custom_object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I endup doing little different way. I used [GVK API](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/gvks.html) to query using custom object API. I listed all the namespaces using corev1api and then did
`list_namespaced_custom_object(group="autoscaling.k8s.io", version="v1", namespace=<namespace-name>, plural="verticalpodautoscalers")`
Python library example is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#list_namespaced_custom_object)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments

From what I see in the [python client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), there is neither documentation or API created for Vertical Pod Autoscaler at this moment.

There is only documentation and API created for [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/). Which may be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AutoscalingV1Api.md).